# Is there programmatic access to android/ios built in device alarm system

Tags: android, ios

For a project, I need to have programmatic access to manage built-in device alarms. I came across androids `AlarmManager` but this seems more focused on actually waking up the application. I'm more interested in manipulating the alarms that you can set yourself manually.

If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no API to access alarms in iOS.  You can use EventKit to manage reminders in calendars.